# MediaWiki Main_Page not shown

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki

I've messed up a little bit with my php cms insallation and now I've problems loading the mediawiki Main_Page and I don't exactly know why. The error thrown by the server is a simple 404, so it doesn't explain that much to me. The only thing that could help me find out the solution is that I changed the virtual host configuration a couple of times in the server (Apache 2.4).

I'm guessing the problem is there but I don't have any further clue about how to solve it.
Has anyone experienced something like this?

I've to add that this is not a short URL problem, as i'm not trying to redirect the articles pages to a specific url, so [this](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) shouldn't be useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, i guess you got some error in your pathing.

Have you tried running it locally via e.g. [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/) ?

Play around with you `local_settings` especially `$wgScriptPath` and `$wgStylePath`.

The error can usually be found in there, and fixed in there. I have been working with MediaWiki the last couple of weeks. If you provide some more info, i might be able to help you some more.